# contentVersion (image/png) created is empty

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

//lightning controller- Here I am capturing the signature in a hidden canvas and extracting the base64 data from it , and sending it to the server side apex

```
     var tCtx = document.getElementById('textCanvas').getContext('2d'),
    imageElem = document.getElementById('Signimage');
    
    tCtx.canvas.width = 720;
    tCtx.canvas.height= 100;
    tCtx.font = "italic 30px monospace";
    var theSignature = n; // name of person -  the text that is to be converted to an img
    tCtx.fillText(theSignature,10, 50);
    imageElem.src = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL();        
   var base64Canvas = tCtx.canvas.toDataURL().split(';base64,')[1];
    component.set('{!v.storeApplicantSign}',base64Canvas);
```

//lightning helper

```
uploadonSubmit: function(component,event,helper) {
        // call the apex method 'saveChunk'
        var action = component.get("c.saveChunk");  
        action.setParams({
            parentId: component.get("v.recordId"),
            base64Data: component.get("v.storeApplicantSign"),   // contains the base64 data 
        });
 
        // set call back 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            // store the response / Attachment Id   
           var result = response.getReturnValue();
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("Success");
              // this.showtheToast();                  
            } else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        // enqueue the action
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

// apex class

//Here decoding the data from the lightning and creating content version

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static Id saveChunk(Id parentId,String base64Data) {                   
         String fileId = saveTheFile(parentId,base64Data,'Signature.png');  
         return Id.valueOf(fileId);
    }



public static Id saveTheFile(Id parentId,String base64Data,String fileName) { 
   base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data,'UTF-8');
    ContentVersion contentVersion = new ContentVersion(
        versionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(base64Data),
        title = fileName,
        pathOnClient = 'Signature'+'.'+'png',
        ContentLocation='S',
        FirstPublishLocationId = parentId);
     system.debug('contentversion data=>   '+contentVersion+'version data ----> '+contentVersion.VersionData);
    insert contentVersion; 
    return contentVersion.Id;
}
```

// File is being created but it's empty that is image is not there / can't be opened as img

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in apex side :
just removed the line :

```
 `base64Data = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(base64Data,'UTF-8'); // this wasn't required
```

removing the above line solved it .